# PHP recursion not changing value in array properly

Tags: php, arrays

This function tries to rename the duplicate names in $a array.

```
public function addToDuplicate($a, $b)
  {
    if (in_array($b, $a)) {
        $b = $b."_1";
        $this->addToDuplicate($a, $b);
    }
    return $b;
  }
```

This function calls the addToDuplicate function

```
public function names($names_data)
  {
    $names= array();
    foreach ($names_data as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($value->name, $news_files)) {
            array_push($names, $this->addToDuplicate($names, $value->name));
        }else{
            array_push($names, $value->name);
        }
    }
    return $names;
  }
```

My $names_data is like

```
0=> #attributes: array:2["id" => 1
"name" => "John"] 
1=> #attributes: array:2["id" => 2
"name" => "John"] 
2=> #attributes: array:2["id" => 2
"name" => "John"]
```

When I run my code I get output

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "John"
  1 => "John_1"
  2 => "John_1"
]
```

But I want to get

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "John"
  1 => "John_1"
  2 => "John_1_1"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your function lacks is the return of the recursion, in your case you return only the first round of the if condition while the return of subsequent calls are lost.
I'll report you under the correct code.

```
public function addToDuplicate($a, $b)
  {
    $values = [];
    if (in_array($b, $a)) {
        $b = $b."_1";
        $values = array_merge($values, $this->addToDuplicate($a, $b));
    } else {
        $values[] = $b;
    }
    return $values;
  }
```

```
public function names($names_data)
  {
    $names= array();
    foreach ($names_data as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($value->name, $news_files)) {
             $names = array_merge($names, $this->addToDuplicate($names, $value->name));
        }else{
            array_push($names, $value->name);
        }
    }
    return $names;
  }
```